# Writing data directly into .DBF files from a mySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, dbf, dbase

What I'm trying to achieve is the ability to write data into a DBF file as a new record using data from a mySQL database through PHP.

I've come across this article (http://dbf-software.com/sql-insert.html), but it looks like standard SQL so I'm not sure it'll work. I'm currently implementing a script to see it does, but the option may be more robust...

The other option is dBase(http://php.net/manual/en/ref.dbase.php), which I've never looked into and seems quite daunting. Before I delve into it I was wondering if this task can be achieved through dbase?

Any other solutions are welcome. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you will be using 2 databases ?

Comment: The .DBF files are external (and shared across many different places), so we can't use these for our web application. The mySQL is used as the backend for our web app. Data is written from the front end into mySQL and then the data (hopefully) will be inserted from the mySQL database into the DBF files.

TL;DR - To avoid record locking in the live DBF files.

Comment: Did you read [this](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-file.html#ImpExpDBMS)? The feature allows you to import data from your MySQL DB to a DBF file (command-line interface supported).